# Prevent Angular 4 from Destroying View/Controller

Tags: javascript, angular, tabs, lifecycle

I am using Angular 4 and I have a tab component from here https://github.com/ng-bootstrap (ngb-tabset).  When I switch back and forth between the tabs, I've noticed that my components are being recreated.  Is there a way I can keep angular from destroying my tab UIs while that particular tab is hidden?

If not, is there better way to structure my service calls?  What I mean is that my x-component.ts calls a x-service.ts to get the initial data.  The controller (x-component.ts) stores the result of this call into an array or an object of some sort.

With my component being destroyed and recreated, my controllers will make these calls over and over again every time the user switches tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is specific to ng-bootstrap and there is an option that changes it: `destroyOnHide`. Just set it to false. See their docs [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/api).

Example: `<ngb-tabset [destroyOnHide]="false"></ngb-tabset>`